# Why do we still need read() and write() system calls, why can't we replace them with ioctl system call?

Tags: c, linux, io

In linux, For all read and write operations we use read() and write() system calls. The same we can do with ioctl() system call also, then why we still need read() and write() system calls?

Is there any security or fast performance while using read() and write() system calls rather than ioctl() ?

Answer (score 2):

If we removed read() and write() then the system would no longer be posix compliant (and much existing software would break). Likewise, if we rely exclusively on linux ioctl system calls then our code is no longer portable to other systems.

Comment: So we still need read and write system calls to support posix compliant.

Comment: @JyothiKumarReddy CONFORMING TO  SVr4, 4.3BSD, POSIX.1-2001.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically *everything* could be done using `ioctl()`. But the purpose of `ioctl()` is to provide a way to perform miscellaneous, device-specific operations. When there are operations that most devices implement, it's better to use a more specific function. This allows the compiler to perform argument type checking. A generic function like `ioctl()` can't check that you've provided parameters appropriate to that operation.

Comment: Yes read() and write() do the argument type checking, Is it for security purpose?

Comment: It's just general coding principles.

Comment: Ok thanks. But argument type checking is not necessary as most of the device specific operations performed with ioctl also not having such checks. And also not(no need of) checking any permissions access as like we do in copy_from_user and copy_to_user.

Comment: That's a compromise. We need a miscellaneous function like `ioctl` because it's not practical to write specific functions for everything we might ever want to do, so we live without argument checking there. But we don't want that for common operations.